# Possible drivetrain problem?

Tags: chain, shifter, drivetrain, freewheel

I recently bought a bike and upon riding it and coasting for a relatively short time I heard a noise that sounded like the chain sort of clicking louder than the freewheel, then eventually the chain jumped up and I’ve been having this issue ever since

Comment: Sounds like the freewheel is jamming.  If this is a new bike take it back where you bought it.

Comment: Would replacing the freewheel solve this issue likely?

Comment: The bike would have to be examined by a bike-aware person.

Comment: Is it a brand new bike or a second hand one? Is the chain trying to get onto a different cog even though you aren't changing gear?